# pandas iat : vscode vs jupiterlab

Tags: pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

I used some code that works on vscode :

> `df.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = thisText`

At first df is not defined, row_marker,column_marker equal zero;
**It creates new line and column correctly !**

I tried the same code in jupiterlab but got an IndexError : I assume it is because the column number is not knowed....

Why is this working in vscode but not in JupiterLab ?
What is the method to add new values manually when we don't know the size of the dataframe ?

---

*New comment : the dataframe exist but is empty*

Comment: No way the code is working with an undefined df - not even with an empty df.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empty dataframe you can add rows via the append method

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
thisText = 'Hello World'
df = df.append({'column': thisText}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hello Peter, I'm parsing an HTML web site, and want to add colums on the same row, then new raw when necessarry, that's why I'm using iat. If I use append it will add a column but will also change the row for the next column, and I don't know how to append column on the same row ....

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern to build a dataframe that can grow in both dimensions:

```
import pandas as pd 
site_no = 0 
df = pd.DataFrame()
while site_no < 4:  # your website counter
    if site_no < 2:  # website with col0 and col1 data
        row = pd.DataFrame(
            {'col0:': 'Hello', 'col1': 'World'}, index=[site_no])
    else:  # website with col2 and col3 data
        row = pd.DataFrame(
            {'col2:': 'Say', 'col3': 'Goodbye'}, index=[site_no])
    df = df.append(row)
    site_no += 1

df
    col0:   col1    col2:   col3
0   Hello   World   NaN     NaN
1   Hello   World   NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     Say     Goodbye
3   NaN     NaN     Say     Goodbye
```

Comment: @Harvey: Would you please consider replying to your post. Volunutarily helping you was a little effort. So I guess I can ask for a little respect ...